# sql netezza check before inserting

Tags: c#, database, insert, duplicates, netezza

I am trying to create a screen for my database to insert,upload,delete and show. Here how it looks.

[image]

I am using `Netezza` database system and obtaining my table from `ODBC`. First, I created a form application in Visual Studio. Then, I added `datagrid` to my form. Thanks to `datagridview`, I added my datasource from its icon by just clicking it and choose my table from that. It automatically brought me a table when I did that.

Here is the code it is generated for me to Show me to table

`this.sPSS_STREAM_INFOTableAdapter.Fill(this.dataSet1.SPSS_STREAM_INFO);`

Then, I noticed that it also could generate insert and update methods or I could overload them. However it has different syntax than I know in netezza. I was able accomplish the insert method like this.

`INSERT INTO "ADMIN"."SPSS_STREAM_INFO" ("IS_AKIS_NO", "IS_AKIS_AD", "IS_AKIS_ACKLM", "PROJE_ADI", "YZLM_OP_ID", "TEST_OP_ID", "KGG_OP_ID") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

So, I am able to insert by filling any columns but of course I need to write something to IS_AKIS_NO because it behaves like primary key in my table even there is no primary key in Netezza but it does not prevent me to add same IS_AKIS_NO number here because I don't have any constraint in netezza. How can type the sql code to check if the value in my first column already exist before I insert?

Answer (score 0):

If your ID field `IS_AKIS_NO` is an auto incrementing value then you can create a `sequence` to help solve your problem.

[Create a Sequence](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/c_dbuser_create_sequence.html)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IS_AKIS_NOseq as integer
START WITH 1 increment by 1
minvalue 1 maxvalue 100000000 no cycle
```

Retrieve the next value from the `sequence`

```
select NEXT VALUE FOR IS_AKIS_NOseq
```